# Installation fails if the MSI is more than 2 GB

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have created an MSI with the size of 2.4 GB, the max cab size is 450 MB. (I don't think I have reach one of the [limits](http://www.msifaq.com/a/1043.htm))

When I use an embed Cab option the installation Fails.

If the cabs are not embed the installation finished successfully.

This is the error from the log.

```
MSI (s) (2C:20) [14:10:47:425]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (2C:20) [14:10:47:515]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (2C:20) [14:10:47:527]: Machine policy value 'LimitSystemRestoreCheckpointing' is 0
MSI (s) (2C:20) [14:10:47:528]: Note: 1: 1715 2: Landa Support Site 
MSI (s) (2C:20) [14:10:47:528]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (2C:20) [14:10:47:529]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1715 
MSI (s) (2C:20) [14:10:47:529]: Calling SRSetRestorePoint API. dwRestorePtType: 0, dwEventType: 102, llSequenceNumber: 0, szDescription: "Setup".
MSI (s) (2C:20) [14:10:49:338]: The call to SRSetRestorePoint API succeeded. Returned status: 0, llSequenceNumber: 33.
MSI (s) (2C:20) [14:10:49:346]: File will have security applied from OpCode.
MSI (s) (2C:20) [14:10:49:347]: Note: 1: 1310 2: 131 3: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\1067489.msi 
The system cannot open the device or file specified.
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:718]: I/O on thread 3216 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:719]: I/O on thread 12088 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:719]: I/O on thread 7480 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:720]: I/O on thread 9380 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:720]: I/O on thread 5924 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:721]: I/O on thread 6172 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:721]: I/O on thread 10924 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:721]: I/O on thread 6432 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:723]: I/O on thread 11628 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:724]: I/O on thread 3204 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168
MSI (s) (2C:20) [14:10:51:727]: MainEngineThread is returning 110
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:760]: Calling SRSetRestorePoint API. dwRestorePtType: 13, dwEventType: 103, llSequenceNumber: 33, szDescription: "".
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:761]: The call to SRSetRestorePoint API succeeded. Returned status: 0.
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:771]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:773]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:773]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (2C:40) [14:10:51:780]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (54:34) [14:10:51:783]: Note: 1: 2755 2: 110 3: F:\Setup.msi 
MSI (c) (54:34) [14:10:51:784]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (54:34) [14:10:51:784]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2755 
DEBUG: Error 2755:  Server returned unexpected error 110 attempting to install package F:\Setup.msi.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2755. The arguments are: 110, F:\Setup.msi, 
MSI (c) (54:34) [14:10:52:526]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (54:34) [14:10:52:526]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (c) (54:34) [14:10:52:527]: Product: Setup -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2755. The arguments are: 110, F:\Setup.msi, 
MSI (c) (54:34) [14:10:52:528]: Back from server. Return value: 110
MSI (c) (54:34) [14:10:52:529]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (54:34) [14:10:52:529]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 14:10:52: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
```

Comment: Must be multi-part, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373988/what-is-the-largest-size-that-a-single-msi-windows-package-installer-file-can-b and https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/what-is-the-maximum-size-that-a-msi-windows-installer-file-can-be

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're okay on the CAB limits, as you referenced, but the .msi file itself has limits. It is a structured storage file using 512 byte sectors; this limits its size to 2GB. While there are ways to make structured storages without these limits, there is no documented way to make an .msi file without them.